# Adding custom text in order preview WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to show a custom text in orders preview in WooCommerce.

[image]

---

I found that public function render_billing_address_column in

### includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php

i could modify the code and add some text there but im looking for way for doing this in another custom plugin

```
 if ( order had this specification ) {
    echo 'my custom text;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of these hooks: `woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start` or `woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end` like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end', 'lets_show_something_in_preview' );
function lets_show_something_in_preview() {
    if ( order had this specification ) { 
       echo 'my custom text'; 
    }
}
```

or

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start', 'lets_show_something_in_preview' );
function lets_show_something_in_preview() {
    if ( order had this specification ) { 
        echo 'my custom text'; 
    }
}
```

or adding a custom column with custom text:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'lets_add_a_new_column_to_admin_order_page' );

function lets_add_a_new_column_to_admin_order_page( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['another_column'] = 'Your Column';
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'column_content_with_custom_text' );

function column_content_with_custom_text( $column )
{
    global $post;

    if ( 'another_column' === $column ) 
    {
        echo "Your Custom Text";
    }
}
```

or edit a specific column by adding custom text: 
[image]

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'column_content_with_custom_text' );

function column_content_with_custom_text( $column )
{
    global $post;

    if ( 'billing_address' === $column ) 
    {
        echo "<b>Your Custom Text</b><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.  i add below code to function.php but not work.

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start', 'lets_show_something_in_preview' );
function lets_show_something_in_preview() {
    if ($order->has_status( 'processing' )) { 
       echo 'my custom text'; 
    }
}

Comment: I tested the code. It prints "my custom text" when I try "if(1)". And I also tested to print $order->ID and it returned 0. So, it does not get $order object itself.

Comment: I will flag your question as a possible duplicate since I found a better answer that will work for you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845664/display-custom-data-on-woocommerce-admin-order-preview

Comment: your code work well in PREVIEW button. http://oi65.tinypic.com/2n712rp.jpg    i want to show text in orders list , not inside the preview ,,,   i mean here https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UZOd.png

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I misunderstood you since you mentioned "preview"... So, adding a new column with custom text is a solution for you or do you need to change the exact column you pictured?

Comment: I have just added 2 more solutions for you. I hope those will work for you. Have a good day.

Comment: thank you. everything goes well.

Comment: is there a way to read a $post_meta and display them there?

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the data you want to display in the column?

Answer (score 1):

thank you MrEbabi your code goes to function and worked well.
also if someone want to read $post_meta from a order and do something they could done it with below code

```
function column_content_with_custom_text( $column ) {
global $post;
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

if ( 'billing_address' === $column ) {
if( empty( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_meta', true ) ) ) {
    echo "<b>Custom Text</b><br>";
}
```