# Display Order total in WooCommerce order quick view

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want to display the order total in the order preview popup like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Show used coupon in WooCommerce order quick view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645923/show-used-coupon-in-woocommerce-order-quick-view/65646722#65646722) answer, You can use the following to add the order total to WooCommerce order quick view:

```php
// Add custom order data to make it accessible in Order preview template
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_get_order_details', 'admin_order_preview_add_order_total', 10, 2 );
function admin_order_preview_add_order_total( $data, $order ) {
    $data['order_total'] = strip_tags( wc_price( $order->get_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) ) );
    return $data;
}

// Display The data in Order preview
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end', 'display_order_total_in_admin_order_preview' );
function display_order_total_in_admin_order_preview(){
    // Call the stored value and display it
    echo '<div><table cellspacing="0" class="wc-order-preview-table"><thead><tr>
        <th class="wc-order-preview-table__column--total">' . __('Total') . '</th>
        <td class="wc-order-preview-table__column--total-amount">{{{data.order_total}}}</td>
    </tr></thead></table></div>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

[image]